Can't go to next line without Ending text in QR code using barcode Printer API
I am generating a QR code in a C++ project and trying to include multiline text. However, whenever I add a line break using \n or \x0A, the QR code generator stops rendering text after the first line break. The rest of the content is not included in the QR code.
Interestingly, this issue doesn't occur with other line break characters like \x0D. Using those characters renders the QR code, but the line breaks don't work as expected. For instance, \x0D doesn't break the text into new lines; instead, the text appears as one continuous line.(it only goes to a new line when I export the scanned QR code to a text file)
I just want to show the data in the QR code in separate lines.
I am using a dll file that came with the barcode printer. I will provide a link to the manual of the library and the API's in the library but also will provide a snippet of the parts that are more related to my problem.
I am using a POSTEK Q8/200 printer and a seagul driver that also came with the printer itself.
QString content = QString::fromUtf8(
    "SomeCompany Inc. \n"
    "www.SomeCompany.com \n"
    "Email: info@SomeCompany.com"
);

how the content is being used in the called function:
int DllHandler::drawQRCode(int x, int y, const QString& content) {

    return PTK_DrawBarcode2D_QR(x, y, 200 , 175, 0, 2, 1, 0, 8,content.toUtf8().constData());
}

the called function in the library:
    PTK_DrawBarcode2D_QR = (DrawQRFunc)library.resolve("PTK_DrawBar2D_QR");

defenition in the header file:
    typedef int (*DrawQRFunc)(int, int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,const char*);


now for the library function and format explanation, I will paste a snipper from each of the most relevant parts and also link the API manual and the page numbers of the relevant parts.
how Strings are handled by the API:
/*
String
The quotation mark character ( ” ) designates the beginning and ending of a string.
The back slash character ( \ ) designates that the character following is a literal and will encode into the
data field. Refer to the following examples:



character
Enter into Data Field




"
\"


\
\\


0x00 – 0x7F
\x00 - \x7F




All print commands and alpha character command, Parameters are case sensitive.
 is “13”of the USASCII decimal system, or “0DH”of the hexadecimal system, namely “enter”
symbol.

*/
the function being used in the API:
/*
PTK_DrawBar2D_QR
This function is used to print a QR barcode.
Syntax:
PTK_DrawBar2D_QR( unsigned int x, unsigned int  y,
unsigned int w, unsigned int v,
unsigned int o, unsigned int r,
unsigned int m, unsigned int g,
unsigned int s, LPTSTR pstr )

Parameters:
         int     x;          ●X coordinates. 

         int     y;         ●Y coordinates. Note:1 dot = 0.125 mm. 

         int     w;         ●Maximum printing width, in dots.  

         int     v;         ●Maximum printing height, in dots.  

         int     o;         ●Set the rotate direction, value range: 0～3. 

         int     r;          ●Set the multiplier values, in dots, value range: (1 - 9). 

         int     m;         ●Select the coding mode of QR, value range:(0 - 4). 

         int     g;          ●Select the error correction level of QR, value range: (0 - 3). 

         int     s;          ●Select the masking pattern of QR, value range: (0 - 8). 

         LPCTSTR pstr;      ●A character string. 



Return Value:  0 -> OK.
Reference Error.txt file.
*/
the document:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xZTO3Bm8Vgk09ySqud7-j0mtWXGpcdBL/view?usp=drive_link
string info is in page 2 and 3
function info is in page 22 and 23
feel free to ask any questions if the information is incomplete or if additional information is needed.

typedef int (*DrawQRFunc)(int, int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,const char*); --  But the function you claim you are calling has the last parameter type as LPCTSTR pstr;      ●A character string.  -- A const char * is not a LPCTSTR, unless the application is compiled as ANSI/MBCS.

@PaulMcKenzie the API has two versions that are Unicode and multi-byte I am using the multi-byte so I believe that the app is compiled as MBCS. And if not, how can I use LPCTSTR in my qt application?

Your header file declaration typedef int (*DrawQRFunc)(int, int,int,int,int,int,int,int,int,const char*); will fail (either at compile-time, or worse, at runtime) if in the future you use the Unicode version of the library.   So you need to figure out how to vary the last parameter, depending on the build type.

@PaulMcKenzie I don't interact with the Unicode version of the library, and the program runs well until I try to go to the next line in the text. Do you think that this might have caused the problem in the \n usage?
